# Overlap Text on Dropdown Menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, jquery-ui-draggable

I have an issue with my Dropdown menu that is overlapped by the content of the page. Here is the jsfiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/yusrilmaulidanraji/qu4fnxLn/
and here is my code:

html:

```
    <div class="dropdown" style="float:left;">
      <button class="dropbtn">Left</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content" style="left:0;">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div id="draggable" class="draggable draggable-text ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle content" title="Click and Drag to the Grid">Company Name</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

JS:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
```

I assume the source of the problem is the draggable class from JQuery-UI. As you could see, the content is draggable and I use a class from JQuery-UI for it. Here is the documentation of the class:
https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

So, is there any solution to make the content to not overlap the dropdown menu?
Thank you in advance.

**Edited**:
Previously I tried to simplify my case but as a result, it has a different chronology. In order to make it precise, I made a new jsfiddle with the case of my actual project (I also tried to simplify it actually, but hopefully it will have the same solution in the end). Here is the jsfiddle of my project:
https://jsfiddle.net/yusrilmaulidanraji/qu4fnxLn/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @AgataB answer, I have found another nice solution. Instead of I change the z-index of the content, I change the z-index of dropdown.

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Now, the content is not overlapping the dropdown, and the draggable is still working.

Answer (score 1):

You can set z-index of the draggable element in CSS with:

```
.draggable {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1
}
```

`z-index: -1` sets it to the back, and it only works on positioned elements, hence the need for both settings. [More on it here.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Note that this will position the draggable element at the back, behind everything including the button. If that's not the intention, I'll let you figure out the rest. Good luck!

Comment: I have tried to put style="z-index: -1;" to the draggable element. Unfortunately, it shuts down the draggable. :(
Do you have another option?

Comment: It works for me, until you click anything in the dropdown menu - is that not desired either?

Comment: Yes for the drag part, it works already. But it overlaps the dropdown menu. https://postimg.org/image/fe8rg8ech/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Douma37/qu4fnxLn/1/ Try this. When you expand the menu, the draggable element is behind it. You just need to set the styles in CSS. EDIT: http://imgur.com/0fGoCvO - have a screenshot

Comment: You are right, it works!
But unfortunately, I suppose there is something wrong within my project. I tried to implement it in my project but it does not work. It's my mistake to not put the entire case, I just tried to make it simple at the first time.
If you dont mind, would like to help me regarding that?
here is the jsfiddle of my project. (I've tried to simplify it as well, hopefully it will have the same result at the end) https://jsfiddle.net/yusrilmaulidanraji/qu4fnxLn/4/

Comment: No, it is **good** that you gave a minimal example. Start with a small one and build up. When you uncomment the last bit of css, it respects the z-index all right: https://jsfiddle.net/Douma37/qu4fnxLn/5/ so the problem lies somewhere else, perhaps with the draggable settings? At a first glance, you can try to make anything that's `.dropped` draggable as well - and after the `.dropped` is assigned, not on load. Hope that will get you on the right track.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118305/discussion-between-agatab-and-yusril-maulidan-raji).

Comment: For the draggable setting, I've managed it through `.draggable` as you can see at line 6. For defining the `.dropped` as draggable, I also have managed it at line 40 and line 23 using `.content`.
Therefore, I am still wondering why it still does not work.